# python scipy.integrate quad and trapz gives two differents result

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying  to integrate a function  using the scipy library:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas  as pd
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.integrate import trapz
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([-1,-0.75,-0.5,-0.25,0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1])*5.4
y = np.array([20.6398,  -45.2398,   -113.8779,  -52.7028,   618.7554,   -52.7028,   -113.8779,  -45.2398,   20.6398])
function = np.polyfit(x, y, 8)


def u(x):
  a = function[0]
  b = function[1]
  c = function[2]
  d = function[3]
  e = function[4]
  f = function[5]
  g = function[6]
  h = function[7]
  l = function[8]
  return  a*x**8 + b*x**7 + c*x**6 + d*x**5 + e*x**4 + f*x**3 + g*x**2 + h*x  + l

  
St =trapz(y,x)
print(St)

Squad, err = quad(u,-5.4,+5.4)
print(Squad)
```

the results are : trapz : 291.2681699999999
quad :           -1598.494351085969

why the results  are different and which is the correct result
this is the graph of the function:
[image]

Comment: Take a look at this plot: `xx = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 400); plt.plot(xx, np.polyval(function, xx))`.  I think you'll see what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

@Warren Weckesser is correct. Your polynomial does not interpolate well. It is known that high degrees of polynomials are not suited for this task.

```
t = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 10**4)
plt.plot(t,u(t))
plt.plot(x,u(x))
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

[image: bad poly interpolation]

`trapz` assumes that the function is is ruffly linear between the points you choose. So if you're actually interested in the integral of this polynomial you have to pick a step size for which the assumption is ok.

```
t = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 10**4)
trapz(u(t),t), quad(u,-5.4,+5.4)[0]
```

gives you twice `-1598.49...`
I assume you're not interested in the polynomial but I also don't know what you want. Maybe you wanted the linear interpolation as in your picture? Then you could do:

```
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline

spl = UnivariateSpline(x,y,k=1,s=0.1)
trapz(y,x), quad(spl,-5.4,+5.4)[0]
```

And you get twice
`291.26...`.
Notice that if you remove the `k=1` and play around with the s parameter `UnivariateSpline` is much much better for interpolation. It also work with polynomials but instead of taking a high degree polynomial to interpolate many points it stitches together polynomials of degree `k`. That's why for `k=1` we get a linear interpolation.

And if you want something else I am afraid you'll have to tell me.

Comment: Thank you   you helped me a lot, well actually  what I am suppose to  is to draw the (x, y) points on a paper (less accurate) or use   AutoCAD  (more accurate) and then AutoCAD has an option  to calculate the area, since I don't have AutoCAD  I used python to  get the function  that fits the (x, y)  points then useed integration to get the area so now  what should I do??

Comment: @NAS The problem is there are infinitely many curves going threw your points. If you have the "do by hand" option and in your context it makes sense to fill it in with straight lines then my answers showed you that that's equivalent to using the `trapz` formula. In that case I would just make sure I understand what I am doing there i.e. read the wikipedia article of it till I know what it does. If it does not make sense to fill in with straight lines read again what I wrote about `UnivariateSpline`. Splines are the right tool for this task. Or ask further here.